# SQL server connection error while using Docker compose

Tags: .net, sql-server, docker, database-connection, blazor-server-side

I am building a Blazor Server application and decided to containerized MS SQL as the database.

Here below are my docker-compose and appsettings.json

Docker-compose:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  NAME.webapp:
    container_name: NAME.app
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}NAMEwebapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: NAME.WebApp/Dockerfile
    ports:
     - "8001:80"
    depends_on:
     - NAME.db
  NAME.db:
    restart: on-failure
    container_name: NAME.db
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
    ports:
     - "8002:1433"
    environment:
     - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
     - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=********
    volumes:
     - NAME-db:/var/lib/sqlserver/data
volumes:
  NAME-db:
```

docker-compose-override.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  NAME.webapp:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=Server=NAME.db,8002;Database=NAMEdb;User Id=sa;Password=********;Encrypt=False
    ports:
      - "80"
```

appsettings.json:

```
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost,8002; Database=NAMEdb; User Id=sa; Password=********; Encrypt=False"
  }
```

Now when I run my program through docker, I get this error:
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server: Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Both my app and db containers are running in Docker Desktop but when I try to re-connect to the database using DBeaver it gives this error:
"Cannot open database "NAMEdb" requested by the login. The login failed. ClientConnectionId:4502489a-4610-4641-ad9f-2f0936eaf1c0"

Initially, with this setup, I was able to connect to DBeaver and see my database and any added entries.
However, recently I have downloaded and installed SQL Server Express and SSMS for other reasons and I suspect that may have something to do with the error.

Here is the link to SQL server docker hub image: https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server

I have tried running the project after stopping SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) through SQL Server Configuration Manager, tried with SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) running as well.

Tried deleting both container and restarting.

Tried cloning the repo into a different folder and starting that project.

Tried changing the Authenticate in DBeaver to Windows Authenticate from SQL Server Authenticate and did not work.

Tried setting the MSSQL_PID to Express from default (Developer)

My password matches the requirement in the docker hub documentation.

I was wondering if there is a fix to get my code to work with docker instead of using my local SQL Server.

Thanks!

Comment: There seem to be a few misunderstandings here: 1) the `ports` define which container ports are exposed to which ports on the Docker host, so `ports: "8002:1433"` is exposing the container's tcp/1433 port on the host's tcp/8002 port; 2) Docker container names are for use with inter-container name resolution, so `NAME.db` should be usable between containers but it won't resolve from the Docker host; 3) each Docker container is essentially a Linux VM with its own networking stack, so from a container's point of view `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` and `::1` all point to the container itself.

Comment: In other words, from the webapp container have you tried `Server=NAME.db,1433;` yet?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I haven't tried "Server=Name.db,1443; in the webapp container. Would you be able to tell me how can I do it? I am not too experienced with Docker